# MYSQL Recuperar copia

Tags: mysql

me encuentro con una situación que no se me había dado hasta ahora.

Tengo una aplicación cuya base de datos es MYSQL. El otro día algo pasó y se perdieron algunos registros.

Ahora me han recuperado la copia de la madrugada en la que paso es perdida y he de recuperar algunos registros de dos tablas de la copia de seguridad.

Lo que me han recuperado es el contenido de la carpeta DATA del MYSQL pero ahora no se como añadir dicha copia con otro nombre para poder extraer los datos que faltan.

Agradezco toda ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Se necesitan más datos para poder responderte. Aunque si tienes tiempo y paciencia, lo más sencillo que se me ocurre con lo que nos cuentas, es que montes una maquina virtual con un debian o similar (mejor si es el mismo server), instalas el mysql (mejor misma versión) y pegas los ficheros que te han pasado en la carpeta correspondiente, después con mysqldump o phpmyadmin podrás recuperar los registros. Aquí puedes ver varias formas de hacerlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files pero básicamente lo que te he dicho.

Comment: Gracias Track3r... a ver si lo consigo. 
lo que me han pasado no es un dump como tal, si no la copia entera de la carpeta DATA del mysql. Claro yo no necesito sustituir todo, solo quiero recuperar unos registros XXX de una de las tablas... No se si con renombrar la carpeta e la base de datos y copiandola es suficiente pero me temo que no. voy a leer ese post que has puesto y a ver que tal

Comment: Te sugiero que lo hagas en una maquina virtual, la puedes liar muy gorda :)

Comment: Gracias Track3r. Si al final se ha recuperado en otra maquina con otra instancia distinta, se ha hecho el dump y se ha recuperado lo que faltaba. Es una base de datos de 40gb, es enorme y cuesta mas moverla que operar con ella...

pense que habría un sistema mas facil pero al ser INNODB pues ha sido asi...

Gracia por todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al amigo Track3r lo he resuelto de esta manera.

La copia del MYSQL es sistema innodb y lo que he hecho ha sido llevar la copia a otro server, la he añadadido y una vez añadida y visible he sacado los datos que me faltaban con un dump y finalmente los he recuperado en la base de datos buena.

Gracias Track3r